# How to use foreach inside array of foreach?

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

I am trying to insert data into database in json where multiple select has multiple option label and value.  Simply I want to insert into database like this:-

```
First select dropdown:-

 {"select":[{"placeholder":"test","options":
 [{"label":"option-label-1","value":"option-value-1"},
  {"label":"option-label-2","value":"option-value-2"},
  {"label":"option-label-3","value":"option-value-3"},
  {"label":"option-label-4","value":"option-value-4"}],
 "type":"select","name":"test","label":"test"},

Second select dropdown:-

{"placeholder":"test2","options":
[{"label":"option-label-1","value":"option-value-1"},
 {"label":"option-label-2","value":"option-value-2"},
 {"label":"option-label-3","value":"option-value-3"},
 {"label":"option-label-4","value":"option-value-4"}],
 "type":"select","name":"test2","label":"test2"}]}
```

But my code show error while insert

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH), expecting ']'
```

My code to get result is

```
publicfunction dropDownField($request)
{
    $value = [];
    if (key_exists("drop-name", $request)) {
        foreach ($request['drop-name'] as $key => $data) {
            $value[] = [
                "type"        => ($request['drop-type'][$key]) ? (($request['drop-type'][$key])) : null,
                "label"       => ($request['drop-label'][$key]) ? ($request['drop-label'][$key]) : null,
                "name"        => ($request['drop-name'][$key]) ? ($request['drop-name'][$key]) : null,
                "placeholder" => ($request['drop-placeholder'][$key]) ? ($request['drop-placeholder'][$key]) : null,
                  foreach ($request['drop-option-label'] as $index => $data) {
                      "options"     => [
                          'label' => ($request['drop-option-label'][$key][$index]) ? ($request['drop-option-label'][$key][$index]) : null,
                          'value' => ($request['drop-option-value'][$key][$index]) ? ($request['drop-option-value'][$key][$index]) : null,
                      ]
                    }
            ];
        }
    }

    return $value;
}
```

Comment: You can not use `foreach` inside `array`

Comment: ok My issue was due to foreach inside array. So, how can I implement foreach inside array. Anyway to do it.

Comment: Use `foreach` to generate a second array then mung that into the first array where you want it.

Comment: Thanks for your idea.  But How I can do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this code:

```
public function dropDownField($request)
{
    $value = [];
    if (key_exists("drop-name", $request)) {
        foreach ($request['drop-name'] as $key => $data) {
            $options = [];
            foreach($request['drop-option-label'] as $key => $data) {
                $options[] = [
                    'label' => ($request['drop-option-label'][$key]) ?($request['drop-option-label'][$key]) : null,
                    'value' => ($request['drop-option-value'][$key]) ? ($request['drop-option-value'][$key]) : null,
                ];
            }

           $value[] = [
                "type"        => ($request['drop-type'][$key]) ? (($request['drop-type'][$key])) : null,
                "label"       => ($request['drop-label'][$key]) ? ($request['drop-label'][$key]) : null,
                "name"        => ($request['drop-name'][$key]) ? ($request['drop-name'][$key]) : null,
                "placeholder" => ($request['drop-placeholder'][$key]) ? ($request['drop-placeholder'][$key]) : null,
                "options" => $options
            ];
        }
    }
    return $value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @rya.I will try

Comment: here, `$key` is overwritten!!

Comment: Good catch on the multi-array index though

Comment: You are awesome rya!

Answer (score 4):

You just need to create another array inside your loop as you're going, then add it to your original array where needed:

```
publicfunction dropDownField($request)
{
    $value = [];
    if (key_exists("drop-name", $request)) {
        foreach ($request['drop-name'] as $key => $data) {

            // new "options" array
            $options = [];
            foreach($request['drop-option-label'] as $index => $data) {
                $options[] = [
                    'label' => $data ?: null,
                    'value' => !empty($request['drop-option-value'][$index]) ? $request['drop-option-value'][$index] : null,
                ];
            }

            // original "return" array
            $value[] = [
                "type"        => !empty($request['drop-type'][$key]) ? $request['drop-type'][$key] : null,
                "label"       => !empty($request['drop-label'][$key]) ? $request['drop-label'][$key] : null,
                "name"        => !empty($request['drop-name'][$key]) ? $request['drop-name'][$key] : null,
                "placeholder" => !empty($request['drop-placeholder'][$key]) ? $request['drop-placeholder'][$key] : null,
                "options"     => $options // <-- new "options" array added here
            ];
        }
    }

    return $value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks  for your answer.but it's still has problem.

Comment: @PawanDongol ... could you be a little more specific?

Comment: ok My problem show error undefined index offset 0 in this line  'label' => ($request['drop-option-label'][$key][$index]) ? ($request['drop-option-label'][$key][$index]) : null

Answer (score 2):

It Can be something like this:

```
public function dropDownField($request)
{
    $value = [];

    if (key_exists("drop-name", $request)) {
        foreach ($request['drop-name'] as $key => $data) {

        /* Defined $var here for option */
         foreach ($request['drop-option-label'] as $index => $data) {
            $var = [
              'label' => !empty($request['drop-option-label'][$index]) ? $request['drop-option-label'][$index] : null,
              'value' => !empty($request['drop-option-value'][$index]) ? $request['drop-option-value'][$index] : null,
                ];
        }


    $value[] = [
                "type"        => !empty($request['drop-type'][$key]) ? $request['drop-type'][$key] : null,
                "label"       => !empty($request['drop-label'][$key]) ? $request['drop-label'][$key] : null,
                "name"        => !empty($request['drop-name'][$key]) ? $request['drop-name'][$key] : null,
                "placeholder" => !empty($request['drop-placeholder'][$key]) ? $request['drop-placeholder'][$key] : null,
                "options"     => $var; //Defined outside foreach loop
            ];
        }
    }

    return $value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Shaunak  it's show undefined index in this line $request['drop-option-label'][$key][$index]

Comment: We need to add `!empty` in turnary to check value.